# Fire a click event on TAB

Tags: reactjs, events, tabs, click

A basic question in js, I have tabs using react-tabs like this :

```
<Tabs>
<TabList>
  <Tab onClick={() =>this.handleSelect(0)} >Travels</Tab>

  <Tab id="detailstrvID" onClick={() =>this.handleSelect(1)}>Traveil details</Tab>

</TabList>

</TabPanel>
<TabPanel>
 <p>
     test
 </p>
</TabPanel>
```

I want to fire a click event from external button and this event allows to swith tabs dynamically

I tried call like this but doesn't work:

```
   let tab =  $('#detailstrvID');
   console.log('tab '+tab)
   tab.click(function () {
    alert('jQuery.click()');
    return true;
   });
```

My need is like the following post :[React- Active next tab while clicking button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696482/react-active-next-tab-while-clicking-button)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full example how to handle Tab press key by using `onKeyDown`

```
   <input type="text" onKeyDown={this.onKeyPress} placeholder='press Tab'/>
```

Then

```
  onKeyPress = (e) => {
      if (e.keyCode === 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return alert('Tab pressed')
      }
}
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wkpp258l95)

Comment: sorry my question is about Tabs reactjs-tab and not Tabulation. Thank you however